# How to understand this piece of C# code?

Tags: c#, mono

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void LoadLevel (string name)
    {
          Debug.Log("Level Loaded for" + name);
          Application.LoadLevel (name);
    }

    public void QuitLevel ()  
    {
          Debug.Log("Request To Exit Game");
          Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to understand so that I can make my own scripts based on that piece of code.

Comment: Which part you don't understand exactly? And please write a better title next time http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new to Stack Over Flow, okay so the

Comment: I meant to enter a blank line, the (string name) right after public  void LoadLevel

Comment: Idk how to use OSF yet

Comment: `Debug.Log("              ");` or `Debug.Log("\n");`. Depends on the logger.

Comment: The string `name` is just a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173114.aspx) argument..

Comment: Nvm I guess i cant explain my self since  idk what i am doing, thanks for the help.... Im just trying to understand the whole piece of code, I barely started to learn C# 3 days ago

Comment: i dont even know what a method is fully or argument Im assuming its like the int to the variable?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a class containing two methods :
What they're doing is pretty clear, I think. Here's how you can use them :

```
LevelManager lvlMgr = new LevelManager();
string lvlName = "Level1";
// To load the level.
lvlMgr.LoadLevel(lvlMgr); // HERE.
// To quit the level.
lvlMgr.QuitLevel();
```

The `string name` part in `public void LoadLevel(string name)` is the argument you pass to the method (see comment named "HERE"), which is used inside the method.
The `debug.log()`is used to write in the output of the debugger.

Comment: faflo 10 , The LevelManager is that a preset already?, And i just confused on the string whats it doing ?

Comment: oh okay i think im getting a little more sorry i didnt finish reading your response

Comment: LevelManager lvlMgr = new LevelManager();

Comment: what does the new mean or whats it meant to do ?

Comment: It means LevelManager is a class, so in your running code, you'll have to instanciate an object of that class in order to call the methods contained inside the class.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with C# and Unity in the past, so I'll do my best to explain what each part of the code does.

First,

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
```

This is the class name and the script name.

Second,

```
public void LoadLevel (string name)  
{
    Debug.Log("Level Loaded for" + name);
    Application.LoadLevel (name);
}
```

The method LoadLevel takes a string variable and passes it to Debug.Log & Application.LoadLevel. Application.Load level will load a level with a specific name in Unity such as "Level 1" for instance.

```
public void QuitLevel ()  
{
    Debug.Log("Request To Exit Game");
    Application.Quit();
}
```

This method takes no variables and is used to exit the level. 
The Debug.Log method in both methods is used to inform you what each method is doing in Unity's console window.
Application.Quit and Application.LoadLevel are both Unity API methods.

Because this class is a public class, you can make a new LevelManager object in a Unity script, and use both of these methods.

For example 
`LevelManager lvlManager = new LevelManager();`
This will create a new level manager object and allow  you to use the LoadLevel and QuitLevel methods.

For the record, the new keyword in Unity shouldn't be used, but it still works.

Comment: what was the old keyword?. is there any difference between them? , oh okay so the string name tells it to take any string its implied?, or is name a preset?, sorry for the hassle :(

Comment: It's not a hassle 
I believe if you run the code in Unity it will ask you to use the AddComponent() method. 
And yes the string name is parameter. 
The parameter will be past to both the methods inside the braces.
So yes, it will take any string you put into LoadLevel (). 
For example 
`LoadLevel("Level 1")`
Will load the Level 1 in your Unity assets folder.

This is the AddComponent() Method : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Comment: public void LoadLevel (string name)  (string Level1) , Oh okay so if I changed name it wouldnt take any string then right only the specific name i assigned it too?

Comment: this script is only good for loading my game into the level i want it to load too? right or what else is it capable?

Comment: If you were going to use that method in another script for example it would be: 

`LvlManager.LoadLevel("Level 1");`
You can drop the public ,void, and the string keyword.
Level 1 in the quotations  represents name in the code above.
So yes, you are right. If you change name, it would take only the string you assigned it to. It's only capable of loading and quitting levels.

Comment: and the AddComponent () method works the same?, I cant read code yet well... I looked at the link you provided but didnt understand much : (, but im assuming its similar?

Comment: The AddComponent() method works similarly, but it's a bit harder to implement. Unity will warn you that you shouldn't use the new keyword, but you can still use it to create a Level Manager object. The AddComponent method basically adds the component to a game object in the scene; you can do that in the inspector. There is a better way to load and quit levels though.

Comment: so name is a preset already or..?, well this is making Much More sense!:)),

Comment: so AddComponent (string name){ Debug.Log("Level Loaded for" + name);
        Application.LoadLevel (name); } would work too?

Comment: not a preset but it already exist in the C# language ?

Comment: Name is just a preset yes. 
`public void LoadLevel (string name)` consider it the framework for how your method should work. It just tells you what the method can take as a preset.  LoadLevel can only take a string that you assign it.
Nah AddComponent() doesn't work that way; it only adds components to a game object like you would in the inspector in Unity by dragging and dropping.

Comment: so something like that AddComponent (button) {  };

Comment: and it has to include the public void ? or

Comment: For example, in the code they show in the Unity API. 
AddComponent() takes no presets; it remains empty. 
What you can do, however is AddComponents like Rigid bodies or colliders, etc. 

For example 
`AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); `this would add a Rigidbody to the gameobject the script is attached to.
You don't need to include public void, that's only when you're making methods or classes.

Comment: ohh okay I see!:)), how can I distinguish which are classes and methods? is there like certain things that can tell me, just for future reference. Wow that Really Helped Man! : ) wish I can give you Karma if this was Reddit

Comment: but this is way better

Comment: Okay that answers all my questions! Thanks!!

Comment: Classes always have the class keyword
Methods can only exist inside of a class in c#
Example:
`public void class myClass(){
void myMethod()
{
  //This is a comment 
}
//end of class 
}
`

Comment: is there any way I can ask you questions in the future?, you really make coding make sense

Comment: I am not sure; I don't come to stack too often. 
But, if I see your questions I'll try to help out if possible.

Comment: Ohh! I see, Its alll good i created my account a long time ago but oftenly use it, didnt know people like you existed in the internet

Comment: Just trying to help the community; we all need some help sometimes. 
I wish you luck with your game! If you ever have other questions make sure to look around, you may find your answer.
You're very welcome and have a goodnight.

Comment: alright man, well im going offline its 12:29 Am where I live, Really Appreciate your help

Comment: Okay thanks!!, Wish you luck in your Path as well! : )